# order by mysql request in java

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

please I have a problem in this query

`ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user order by"+var);`

I can get the valor of var, but it can't be be executed.
var variable i get it through

`<th><a href="ManageUser?action=order&var=nom">Nom</a></a> </th>`

in DAO  I have.

```
public static ArrayList Order(String var) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
     {
         ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
         Connection con = createDBConnection();
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user order by nom");
         int i=0;
           while(rs.next())
            {
              User cb= new User();
              cb.setID(rs.getInt(1));
              cb.setNom(rs.getString(2));
              cb.setPrenom(rs.getString(3));
              cb.setEmail(rs.getString(4));
              cb.setStatut(rs.getString(5));
              cb.setPassword(rs.getString(6));
              cb.setDate(rs.getDate(7));
              list.add(cb);
              i++;
             }
          stmt.close();
          con.close();
          return list;
    }
```

please HELP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user order by"+var);
                                                             ^---missing space
```

without that space, you get

```
... order bysomefield
           ^---
```

which is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you a lot brother. it was the mistake